# Error exception : Undefined variable that's been declared. Lumen

Tags: php, exception, lumen

So, for some reason i'm getting an Error exception and i can't find the bug. This is my controller (Posts::table = 'table') and (Posts::PK = 'id')

```
public function edit(int $postId): View
{

        $post = app('db')
        ->table(Posts::TABLE)
        ->select(
          '*'
        )
        ->where(Posts::PK, $postId)
        ->first();
        $title = $this->_titleEdit;

    return view('posts.edit', compact(
        'post',
        'title'
    ));

}
```

and this is my view.

```
<form action="<?=route('posts.update',['postId' => $postId]) ?>" method="post">
```

Comment: What variable is undefined?

Comment: Guessing `$postId` in the view?, where is that defined?

Comment: My bad, i was using $postId as a variable, i had to change it to $post->id and then it worked.

Comment: that be it, or pass it via your compact.